# ¿Funcion para mostrar datos en un modal?

Tags: javascript, php, html, datatables, botón

les cuento; tengo este código con html y javascript que me muestra un datatable e imprime los datos con ajax, hasta ahí perfecto, pero necesito que ese botón de "mostrar" al darle click me abra una ventana modal en la que se me muestre el contenido de otro archivo php, en el cual estaran datos almacenados que estan relacionados con la fila seleccionada. Gracias

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    Featured
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <!-- tabla-->
                <table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>codigo</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Registro.</th>
                            <th>fianzae</th>
                            <th>status</th>
                            <th>accion</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tfoot>
                        <tr>
                            <th>codigo</th>
                            <th>Nombre</th>
                            <th>Tipo</th>
                            <th>Registro.</th>
                            <th>fianzae</th>
                            <th>status</th>
                            <th>accion</th>
                        </tr>
                    </tfoot>
                </table>
                    <!-- tabla-->
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#example').DataTable({
            ajax: 'php/prueba.php',
            columns: [
                { data: 'ITEM' },
                { data: 'NOMBRE_DE_AUXILIAR' },
                { data: 'TIPO_DE_AUXILIAR' },
                { data: 'N_DE_REGISTRO' },
                { data: 'ASEGURADORA' },
                { data: 'ESTATUS' },
                {defaultContent: "<button class='mostrar btn btn-info'>mostrar</button>"},
 ],

});
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Puedes usar la función .load() de jquery

Comment: Puedes usar los data-attribute para el botón de mostrar. Ejemplo: data-id="el_id_que_quieras_mostrar", luego capturas ese ID con javascript usando el evento onclick() y envías el ID con ajax a un archivo php. Luego retornas un array con toda la información y la asignas a cada id de los inputs del modal

Comment: La idea de @RicardoPortillo no está tan descabellada, incluso puedes colocar una columna con el ID de ese registro, renderizar un button y con el evento onclick tomar el valor de esa columna ID y mandarlo a un script php con AJAX para consultar en la base de datos